# How to capture the keyboard "Return" event on iPhone browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, keyboard

Is there a way to capture the event in jquery/javascript when a user hits the "Return" key in the iphone browser keyboard? I'm trying to either hide the keyboard on the press or activate some function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeyup=function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13){
        $('inputID').blur();
        //rest of function

        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Are you using a library?

***Update***
Depending on the application, an input submit would hide the keyboard and trigger a function:

```
<form id="searchForm" OnSubmit="doSearch(this.searchTerm.value); return false;">  
  <input type="search" name="searchTerm" autocorrect = "off" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" class="hidden" />
</form>
```

You could even hide the input button with CSS: `.hidden {display: none;}`

Comment: doesn't seem to work. using the jquery and jquery mobile libraries.

Comment: How about triggering a function via input submit?

Comment: It does work when I put alerts inside the function, but if I want the keyboard to disappear, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is what hides the keyboard:

```
$('#inputID').blur();
```

Comment: Yup! Did you want help putting it into a function?

Comment: Haha, no; I just had no idea that was the function.